# Enumerating verbs where just one is used with preposition: correct placement?

Tags: verbs, prepositions, word-order

I need some advice about the proper placement of the preposition **"on"** in the following sentence:

> This is a tool used for creating, collaborating on, and presenting
>   design prototypes.

In my understanding, it makes sense to put **"collaborating on"** last in the list as it's the only one using a preposition:

> This is a tool used for creating, presenting and collaborating on
>   design prototypes.

However, I dislike this order as I believe it modifies the meaning of the sentence. It doesn't follow the logical sequence of events: first create, then collaborate, finally present.

I'd appreciate some advice if the first quoted sentence is grammatically correct.
Thank you!

Comment: "*collaborating on* last in the list" -- please don't; it's fine and much better the way it is. From the point of view of grammar, semantics as well as readability. As for logical sequence, see below.

Comment: Having been a professional product design engineer, it seems to me that collaboration is correctly placed between creation and presentation. Your mileage may vary.

Answer (score 1):

> This is a tool used for creating, collaborating on, and presenting design prototypes.

This is grammatically correct.

As you noted, this is the logical sequence of events: first create, then collaborate, finally present.

When you mix transitive verbs (i.e., which are immediately followed by their objects) and verbs that that take prepositions, I would suggest

- using the natural order, if there is any;
- if there is no natural order, ending with a transitive verb (thus avoiding ending with a preposition, and thus avoiding that the reader (initially) wrongly parses the sentence as if the proposition applies to all the verbs);
- and finally, if still possible, starting with a transitive verb (but this is just my æsthetic preference that can be ignored when other considerations take precedence).

Also, when the penultimate verb has a preposition, use a serial/Oxford/Harvard comma between the preposition and the conjunction, even if you normally don’t.

Your sentence checks all the boxes.

Comment: While I agree with you, I spent a good bit of time looking for such advice in reputable pubs and blogs and didn't find anything. Did you come across anything you can cite?